# The principal branch of $\sqrt{z}$ maps $\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$ onto the right half plane - $\{Re(z)>0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have heard my professor say a couple of times that:

> The principal branch of $\sqrt{z}$ maps $\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$ onto the right half plane - $\{Re(z)>0\}$

but never realized why is that true.

Can anyone provide an explanation or a proof for that statement.

Comment: Did you mean $\operatorname{Re}z>0$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z\in\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$, then $z=re^{i\theta}$, for some $r>0$ and some $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi)$. So, $\sqrt z=\sqrt re^{i\theta/2}$. Since $\frac\theta2\in\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$, $\operatorname{Re}\sqrt z>0$.